# Oracle charlist wildcard

Tags: oracle

The following SQL statement in `SQL server` selects all customers with a City starting with `"b", "s", or "p"`:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE '[bsp]%';
```

but it does not work in `Oracle 11g`.
Thanx in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [REXEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm):

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE City REGEXP_LIKE '^[bsp]%$';
```

I think that Oracle only supports `%` (any number of characters) and `_` (any single character) wildcards when using `LIKE`.

If you want to use plain `LIKE` you could write your query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE 'b%' OR City LIKE 's%' OR City LIKE 'p%';
```

Answer (score 1):

To find customers whose city starts with b, s or p, this is how done in oracle.
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (City, '^[bsp]');

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `OR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Customers
WHERE  City LIKE 'b%'
OR     City LIKE 's%'
OR     City LIKE 'p%';
```